# Install dont listed ubuntu package by aptitute

Tags: package-management, 18.04, xubuntu, aptitude

I need to install those package from ubuntu packages:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libssl1.1

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 with aptitude.

When I'm searching for that in aptitude gui, there is only "lib1.0.0-dbg" package found.

How to install libssl1.1 directly from package URL?

Comment: Please edit your question and post of the results of a simulated libssl1.1 installation using the command `sudo apt-get install -s libssl1.1` To install  libssl1.1 for real, run the same command without the `-s` option.

Comment: your command also worked after adding repository to sources list

Answer (score 0):

You should add repository to your sources list: `sudo echo 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list && sudo aptitude update`

Comment: The `sudo` only has effect on the `echo` command, not the redirection of the output. Try `echo 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list` instead.